# HBase batch operation for checkAndMutate

Tags: hbase

I am trying to combine multiple checkAndMutate operations in one single batch, but looks like it's not supported by HBase client.

On Apache Jira I found this ticket : [Support for batch version of checkAndPut() and checkAndDelete()](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8458)

Ticket is in the open state and the last comment is from 2013.

Does somebody know if batch is supported for checkAndXXX operations by HBase client API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is still not available and Jira is still open.

Also this api doc doesnt mention those batching methods: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.2.0/apidocs/index.html

Comment: If you really need it. You can try implementing it and submitting a patch.